# What is difference between these two styles of writing?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

> He was smart and handsome.
>
> He was smart and **he was** handsome.
>
> First looking at the writing, it was beautiful. It was eloquent, mature, and really drew you into the story.
>
> First looking at the writing, it was beautiful. It was eloquent, **it was** mature, and **it** really drew you into the story.

[Source of 2nd example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932549935)

Is there any usage, or meaning differences between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to meaning there is no difference. Both sets of sentences have the same meaning.

The use of *he/it was* can help the writer draw emphasis to those adjectives by interrupting the flow of the sentence, but this is more of a stylistic choice than one dictated by grammar.